# Replace On Screen Text

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am writing a code for this game where you get a point every time you click on a ball. Your total score should be reflected at the top where the `points` variable is keeping your score. However the score is being printed on top of itself each time. Meaning that when you go from 0 points to 1 point, the 1 is printed over the 0 and so on. I know I have to remove or replace the previous score before printing the new one but I am new to JavaScript and I am not sure how to go about this.

My code:

```
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 550);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 350);
var r = 40;
var points = 0;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(550,350);
  background(0);
}

function draw() {
  fill (255)
  ellipse (x, y, r, r)
  text(("Score:" + points), width/2, 40)
}

function inside(mx, my){
    let d = dist(mx, my, x, y);
    return d < r - 10;
  }

function mousePressed() {
   if(inside(mouseX, mouseY)){
  points++; 
  }
}
```

Comment: using `innerText` or `innerHTML` to display your score will work

Comment: @coder This is the line of my code that prints the score : ``text(("Score:" + score), width/2, 40)``

Comment: ahh sorry i didnt see that xD

Comment: @coder I have no real experience using ``innerText`` could you show me an example?

Comment: @Rivf, Where is the definition for it `text()`?

Comment: @Rivf you can see my answer below and see if that is what you want, im using really simple DOM to display the score

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try like this by creating div.

```js
var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 550);
var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * 350);
var r = 40;
var points = 0;
let scoreDiv = null;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(550,350);
  background(0);
  scoreDiv = createDiv('');
  scoreDiv.position(width / 2, 40)
  scoreDiv.style('color', '#FFFFFF');
}

function draw() {
  fill (255)
  ellipse (x, y, r, r)
  scoreDiv.elt.innerText = `Score: ${points}`;
}

function inside(mx, my){
    let d = dist(mx, my, x, y);
    return d < r - 10;
  }

function mousePressed() {
   if(inside(mouseX, mouseY)){
    points++; 
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/p5@1.3.1/lib/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer that was exactly what I was looking for. Could you possibly edit your answer and adapt it to the code I have on my question? I changed the code on my question so I want that to be reflected in the answer as well.

Comment: @Rivf, updated. Btw, earlier version of that game was fun. I scored around 150 and lost. :)

Answer (score 0):

hmm you can simply use `innerText` to display your score

```html
<p id="score"></p>
```

```js
function mousePressed() {
  var hhi = dist (hballx, hbally, mouseX, mouseY)
  ellipse (hballx, hbally, hballsize, hballsize)
  if (hhi < hballsize/2) {
    hballx = (getRandomInt(550))
    hbally = (getRandomInt(350))
  score = score + 1;
document.getElementById("score").innerText = score; // it will replace the previous score if the score changes 
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm running this on https://editor.p5js.org/ and I am getting an error for Uncaught Syntax Error.

Comment: @Rivf you have to put the <p id="score"></p> on your html file

Comment: @Rivf i have edited the code you can try it, i dont see anything wrong with the syntax thi

Comment: Oh but I am not using HTML, that is why I am getting an error I believe. I am using JavaScript.

Comment: @Rivf you can use html together with javascript in https://editor.p5js.org/ i just tried it and it works, you do not know how to use html?

Comment: Not really hahah

Comment: Ok, I got it but it prints the score outside of the screen. Like it is not within the display.

Comment: hmm yeah thats kinda the problem, you probably have to use css to move it inside the screen. thats the only way i know xD